# Programmatically create admin order with pre-populated basket & customer

Tags: adminhtml, quote

I'm working on a quote system where I want the admin to be able to activate it, which will then forward them to the create new order page in Adminhtml, `sales_order_create`.

<del>I want this page to already have a customer assigned & products selected.</del>

Edit:

I'd like to be able to pre-populate the quote for the Adminhtml page for creating an order.

Here's an example of creating a cart quote on the front-end:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
if ($product){
    if ($product->isSaleable()){
        $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    }
}
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
$cart->save();
```

I want to do this, but in the backend (`sales_order_place`)

I'm looking at the code in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php` and it looks like `adminhtml/session_quote` would be the model I'd be aiming to use.

So the workflow would be:

1. Set up quote object
2. Call `$this->redirect('*/sales_order_create');`
3. The admin will then be redirected to the create new order page with a customer **already** selected and the basket **already** populated with products

Would really appreciate some input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very possible. Here is a very scaled back version of how to accomplish this task.

### Explanation:

The `adminhtml/session_quote` object provides access to a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` object. This object is associated with the session, so the changes made to it are persisted. Do what you would like to the quote object. The items are loaded via `$this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();` (in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items`).

Depending on how you are going to use this, you may need to clear the session:

```
if (is_object($this->_order)) {
    $this->_order->clearInstance();
    $this->_order->reset();
}
$this->_order = null;

$this->_orderCreator = null;
$this->_json = null;
$this->_orderData = null;
$this->_orderItems = null;
$this->_customer = null;

$this->_getSession()->unsetSpecificData();

Mage::unregister('rule_data');
```

### Code:

```
protected $_orderCreator;
protected $_store;

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_initSession();

    $quote = $this->_getSession()->getQuote();

    // TODO: REPLACE FOLLOWING CONSTANT WITH PRODUCT(S)
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(16);
    $quote->addProduct($product, 1);
    $quote->save();

    $this->_redirect('*/sales_order_create');
}

/**
 * Retrieve order create model
 *
 * @return  Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create
 */
protected function _getCreateModel()
{
    if (!$this->_orderCreator) {
        $this->_orderCreator = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/sales_order_create');
    }

    return $this->_orderCreator;
}
/**
 * Retrieve session object
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote
 */
protected function _getSession()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');

    return $session;
}

/**
 * Initialize order creation session data
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController
 */
protected function _initSession()
{
    $this->_getSession()->clear();

    // TODO: SET CUSTOMER HERE
    $this->_getSession()->setCustomerId(1);

    $this->_getSession()->setStore($this->_getStore())
        ->setStoreId($this->_getStore()->getId());

    return $this;
}

protected function _getStore()
{
    if (!$this->_store) {
        // TODO: SET STORE HERE
        $this->_store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(1);
    }

    return $this->_store;
}
```

Comment: This works well, but it is setting quote price as "0" all the time, not sure why?

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `$quote->save()`? If so, I would step through that function and especially look at the quote's collectTotals function to see what is going awry.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had `loop` and was saving `quote` inside loop, which was giving me trouble. After I place `$quote->collectTotals()->save();` after the loop, it is working fine. Thanks again.