# Remove an item from admin order quote and add new item programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, create-order

I am working on a project that needs to tweak **admin order creation** function of magento.

I need to remove an item and then add another item programmatically while creating order.

For example, few items are already added to order, now if product id matches with `my_product_id`, remove that product from `quote` and add new product (`my_new_product`) to order.

It will not be from `observer`, since I will need to add a **button** to call this action and do the job.

I have successfully added a button and linked to my custom controller.

I have gone through loads of links, but no luck.

Please suggest.

Comment: plese  give a screen where are you want to this button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging up for few days, I have been able to get the result.

A big thanks to **@lloiacono** for pointing me to right direction, however his/her answer wasn't good enough.

**In my controller file:**

```
public function removeAndAddAction()
{
    $quote = $this->_getSession()->getQuote();
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
        $quote->removeItem($item->getId());
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        $quote->addProduct($product, 1);
    }
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    $this->_redirect('*/sales_order_create');
}

//get session
protected function _getSession()
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');

        return $session;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Since you only need to tweak the existing admin order creation you could hook to: **sales_order_save_before** or **adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data** but make sure you add this in to the `<adminhtml>` node in your `config.xml`.

Once in your Observer.php you can remove the items you wish, I would instead try to hook to a quote event also in the `<adminhtml>` node and then remove the item at a quote level if possible.

To add an item to the quote:

```
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($eventArgs));
$quote->save();
```

To remove an item from the quote:

```
$quote->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
```

Then you can have magento create the admin order:

```
$adminSalesOrderCreate = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create');
$adminSalesOrderCreate->setQuote($quote)->save();
```

There is a very complete answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/15050/5913

Comment: I have to get quote from admin create order section. Or is it onepage checkout in admin too?

Comment: yes, do it from admin. And also make sure you use Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create'); Check my updated answer

Comment: Big thanks to you @lloiacono for pointing me towards right direction.