# How to add particular product into cart programmatically at admin side

Tags: admin, addtocart, programmatically

Many a times you have heard or seen about how to add particular product into shopping cart programmatically at frontend side. But I want to do the same at admin side.

Suppose, I have product 'SLR Camera Tripod'and I have one button say PayNow in my admin area.

I also have pre-defined customer so there is no need to attempt other beginning steps of admin side order creation process.

When I click on this PayNow button Product 'SLR Camera Tripod' should be added into cart automatically and I should directly redirect on order placement page at admin side.

[image]

Is there any snippet available for this? Hope you understood my concern and can guide me well.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that these item are simple products

Take a look at [Programmatically create admin order with pre-populated basket & customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/programmatically-create-admin-order-with-pre-populated-basket-customer/15050#15050)

Create a module with a admin controller

```
protected function _getSession()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');

    return $session;
}

public function addAction(){
    $product_id = 1; // get product id from add to cart button

    //$this->_initSession();
    $session = $this->_getSession();
    $session->clear();

    $quote = $this->_getSession()->getQuote();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $quote->addProduct($product, 1);
    $quote->save();



    $this->_getSession()->setStore($this->_getStore())
    ->setStoreId($this->_getStore()->getId());
    $this->_redirect('*/sales_order_create');
}
```